# how to load the images in java runnable jar?

Tags: java, swing, icons

When I convert my project into runnable jar the same system, the image is loading in the output. But when I tried in another system, the image failed to load? how to give the image URL rather then using c: ?please help on this?

```
JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar("Toolbar", JToolBar.HORIZONTAL);

JButton capturebut = new JButton(new ImageIcon("C:\\sampleprojects\\
       compare\\shankar\\src\\capture.gif"));

capturebut.setToolTipText("Capture");

toolbar.add(capturebut);
```

Comment: use a relative path for your images. relative to ur class file. and add those images n jar file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `getResourceAsStream`

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html

http://www.jugpadova.it/articles/2006/02/05/accessing-a-resource-within-a-jar

Answer (score 8):

You need to put the image file into the JAR file, then use the `getResource()` method of `java.lang.Class` to get an URL that references the file which is within the JAR file; right now your code is loading the image file directly from your filesystem instead of from in the JAR file.

The string you pass to `getResource()` depends upon where you put it in the JAR file.  If the class doing this is class `Foo` in package `com.acme.bar`, you could put `capture.gif` in the same `com\acme\bar\` subdir of the JAR file (in the same directory as the `Foo` class), and do

```
JButton capturebut = new JButton(new ImageIcon(Foo.class.getResource("capture.gif")));
```

This is because calling `getResource()` on a class with a relative name (not starting with `/`) will look for the resource under the same directory as where the class file for that class is sitting.

On the other hand, you could  make a `resources\images` sub-directory under the root of the JAR file, and instead of `"capture.gif"` use `"/resources/images/capture.gif"`. Starting the name with a '/' makes it search starting at the root of the JAR file, instead of relative to where the class file is.

Comment: Finally, a nice explanation rather than just links and code examples :)